# Dots in snekfetch request are causing a problem

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get data from a json file with snekfetch for my discord bot but I have a problem...

This is a part of the json file

```
"nodes":{
    "main.c10":{
        "online":1624,
        "inbattles":829
    },
```

If I want to get "online" number I should write this

`var c10 = r.body.nodes.main.c10.online;`

but with the dot after main is interpreting the request like this:

```
"nodes":{
    "main {
         .c10":{
            "online":1624,
            "inbattles":829
          }
    },
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Sidenote: please use tags to describe your problem. For example, use [tag:discord.js] only for questions that are specifically related to the discord.js library. This question should be tagged [tag:javascript] or [tag:nodejs]. I've already edited it, but keep that in mind next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access that property with square brackets:

```js
var c10 = r.body.nodes['main.c10'].online;
```

---

*Edit in response to comments:*
In this case `r.body` is a buffer, and so you need to first convert it to an object, only then you can access its properties like `.nodes`. You can find a working demo [here](https://repl.it/@FedericoGrandi/SO-Demo-Dots-in-snekfetch-request-are-causing-a-problem).

```js
JSON.parse(r.body.toString()).nodes['main.c10'].online
```

Comment: This is not solving my problems...
(node:81848) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'main.c10' of undefined

Comment: That means that `r.body.nodes` is undefined: I don't know how to help you in this case, since the question is not about that :\ You may have to check your code or add the entire json to the question

Comment: In that code you wrote `r.nodes` while in your question you wrote `r.body.nodes`: which is the right one?

Comment: r.body.nodes, I was only trying to remove body but without results

Comment: I recreated your code and found the issue: you didn't noticed that `r.body` is a Buffer. In my answer you'll find how to resolve the problem, there's also a working demo :)

Comment: Happy to hear that :)